# Can I find out ethereum address?

Tags: wallets, addresses, password, presale

I bought ethereum from the presale. I have a presale wallet and I do not know the password.  Is there a way I can find out the address?

Answer (score 1):

Open the wallet with notepad and you will find on the end "ethaddr":your address.